# azure durable function saving the same data multiple times/duplicating data

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Im converting a long running azure function to durable functions.
The workflow is as follows:

- durable function 1 gets config data from keyvault & environment variables and returns them in a dictionary.
- second durable function takes this dictionary, connects to a database and checks a database to see if this is a full load or delta load.
- third durable function takes the dictionary of config values and queries active directory via graph API to get all or delta of users.
  This last function calls a regular method to save each "page" of 200 users received from Active Directory to a database.

We have 40,000 users, but when the process completes, there are 70,000+ records saved, many of which are duplicates.

Questions

- Are these duplicates because of the non durable regular method used to send the data to the database, or something else?
- is there any issue with a durable function calling a normal method/function or can this cause issues?

Update:
I can see in the output that one of the durable functions is being executed 5 times, even though i only call it once. i have no idea why this is.

Update2:

Ive stepped through saving the first page of data. the code only executes once, but the data is stored twice!

Does azure functions spin up multiple instances or have some scaling that could cause this to happen?

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a race condition. Perhaps either multiple activity functions are being kicked off or the workflow is replaying and processing data more than once.

Comment: i dont think theres a race condition here, the code worked fine as a normal function, it just took too long to run. When i breakpoint the orchestrator function, it seems to be jumping all over the place. I assumed this was just something to do with how durable functions worked. if i break in the actual method getting the data, it looks to run as expected. not sure why breakpointing in the orchestrator jumps around so much.

Comment: Update: I just noticed in the cmd output from running the function, its calling the GetUsersFromAD function 5 times, each with a different ID. I have no idea why its doing this. updated main post with a pic

Comment: Orchestrators replay after calling each Activity function. Are you `await`ing your `CallActivityAsync<>("GetUsersFromAD"...)`?

Comment: yes. I am using await in a number of places. on the CallActivityAsync and when querying azure AD with the graph client

Comment: OK, difficult to comment any further without seeing some code. The calls are only ~10 seconds apart so I'm wondering if you have a silent failure/uncaught exception and that's causing the Activity to be replayed because second and subsequent times around there's no return value from the last execution. But I'm poking around in the dark. Use of the `IDurableOrchestrationContext.IsReplaying` Property might help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the orchestrator function code.

The orchestrator function code should be deterministic [as explained in these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints). Perhaps this is not the case and the `GetUsersFromAD` activity gets called with different input arguments each time the orchestrator function replays?

Debugging an orchestrator function can be confusing due to the replay nature. If you want more info on how Durable Functions work (incl the checkpointing & replay) [this video](https://youtu.be/ARhgG7OeoX0) can help.

Comment: I tried moving the code to save the data to a database from a separate non durable method, into the durable function and the issue appears to be resolved. This indicates that calling a non durable method within a durable function is not to be relied upon. This is a shame as it causes poor coding practice, i.e. duplicating code in many places inside a single function instead of creating a supporting method and writing the code once.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you moved where exactly. The best way to deal with code that is not deterministic is to put that code in an activity function. So there would not be a need for code duplication. But I might not get your use case completely.

Comment: Actually the linked video does not mention checkpointing and replay.