# Do Azure Functions execute multiple instances of a function?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I am experiencing some very strange Azure function behavior.

I have a function that queries Azure Active Directory, gets each page of 200 users, passes it to a method that saves the page to a database.

I have stepped through the code, its executing linearly, there is no race condition or looping I can see, yet the data is being saved twice!

Also, with regard to Visual Studio, when stepping through the code using breakpoints, the breakpoint is jumping all over the place each time I press <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Is there any behavior in Azure Functions that would cause this?

Comment: What triggers the function? Are you sure it isn't a fault in the code? Did you take a look at the logging to investigate multiple instances are in use or not? There is just not enough information to get going.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [azure durable function saving the same data multiple times/duplicating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029758/azure-durable-function-saving-the-same-data-multiple-times-duplicating-data)

Answer (score 0):

- Without looking into the code, it's hard to get the resolutions. But as per the below statement.

> I have stepped through the code, its executing linearly, there is no race condition or looping I can see, yet the data is being saved twice!

- Whenever the function gets called it will replay every time with different input arguments.
- You can have a look on Azure Durable functions [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints) for better understanding
- Also, you can have a look on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72033927/15969833) with related discussions.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting, it seems the duplicates are only comming from the delta query, but not if simply get all users.

In the interests of time we are avoiding deltaquery for the moment and will come back to it at another time.

Thanks for the replies on this.